# How to obtain operator references from Python in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I can see reference edges attached to operators in tensorboard but how can I pull them out of the related tensor/operator programmatically?

**Example:**

The below code example creates the resulting tensorboard visualisation:

Code:

```
with tf.name_scope('blah') as scope:
  a = tf.constant(5.3, name='alpha')
  b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]), name='b')

add = a+b
ass = tf.assign(b,add,name="ass")
```

Visualisation:

[image: A visualisation of the code with the ass operation open]

More in-depth visualisation, with `b` expanded:

[image: A visualisation of the code with the ass operation expanded]

However, if I examine the varaiable `ass` in my code, or `ass.op`, I can find no way of obtaining a reference back to the variable being assigned to, `b`. There is bound to be such a thing but I simply cannot find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found it.

```
ass.op.inputs[0]
```

Is a tensor with dtype `float32_ref`.

It is the `_ref` part that had been missing.